# C# return local ref variable

Tags: c#

I'm coming from a c++ background and working in C#.
Can anyone explain why this is valid (if it is):

```
public int[] GetArray(int elementCount)
{
    int[] newArray = new int[elementCount];

    return newArray;
}
```

"newArray" is a ref type? Is this books example wrong or can we safely return a reference in c#?

Comment: Yes, the variable *newArray* itself points to the memory location start point of the array in `heap`. Hence it is a `ref type`.

Comment: It would seem I just mixed up a c++ & c# reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newArray` is allocated on the heap - you are then returning the heap variable to the caller, which is safe.

My C++ is rusty, but this is roughly equivalent to:

```
int* Class1::CreateArray(int elementCount)
{
    // heap allocation + return a pointer to the first element
    return new int[elementCount]; 
}
```

AFAIK the unsafe return of references to (local) stack allocated variables cannot be achieved in C# without the use of `unsafe` code, e.g. C++ code like this is not possible in C#:

```
int* Class1::CreateArray()
{
    int newArray[5]; // stack allocated
    return newArray; // Or &newArray[0]
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the equivalent of returning a pointer (initialized and pointing to memory newly allocated on the heap) in c++, would this be correct?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding - yes, you are returning a reference to a heap object - I've tried to dust off my C++ skills. One major difference is garbage collection in C# - in C++ you would need to delete the heap object at some point (or use smart pointers), something we can be blissfully ignorant with in C#.